# g++ generates incorrect targets for header file dependencies

Tags: c++, makefile

This is a Makefile for a small C++ project where both source files (.cpp) and header files (.o) are in the "src" directory.

```
BINARY          := pong
SRCS            := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJS            := ${SRCS:.cpp=.o}

DEBUG           := -g

SDL_INCLUDE     := `sdl2-config --cflags`
SDL_LIB         := `sdl2-config --libs` -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2_mixer

CPPFLAGS        := $(SDL_INCLUDE)
CXXFLAGS        := $(DEBUG) -Wall -std=c++11
LDFLAGS         := $(SDL_LIB)

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(BINARY)

$(BINARY): $(OBJS)
    $(LINK.cc) $(OBJS) -o $(BINARY) $(LDFLAGS)

depend: .depend

.depend: $(SRCS)
    @- $(RM) .depend
    @- $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -MM $^ > .depend;

include .depend

clean:
    @- $(RM) $(BINARY)
    @- $(RM) $(OBJS)
    @- $(RM) .depend
```

Everything works as expected, except that in the generated ".depend" file that contains header file dependencies, the targets (object files) are incorrect.

For example, I would like to have:

```
src/main.o: src/main.cpp src/pong.hpp
```

Instead of:

```
main.o: src/main.cpp src/pong.hpp
```

Comment: May be this will help:
"Unless specified explicitly (with -MT or -MQ), the object file name consists of the basename of the source file with any suffix replaced with object file suffix"
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html

Comment: For anyone interested, I solved it by replacing:

`@- $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -MM $^ > .depend;`

With:

`@- $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -MM $^ | sed -r 's|^([^ ])|src/\1|' > .depend;`